# some unexpected behavior on opencl in xcode and bash?

Tags: c, xcode, macos, bash, opencl

I am trying to run an helloworld from Apple developer [site](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/OpenCL_Hello_World_Example/Introduction/Intro.html), but it fails both in xcode and both from shell:

```
clang -framework OpenCL helloworld.c -o helloworld && ./helloworld
Error: Failed to create a device group!
```

`helloworld.c` is attached at the end of the question.

but if I run the code in the accepted answer in [How can i test for OpenCL compability?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892955/how-can-i-test-for-opencl-compability)

I get:

```
Device Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2557M CPU @ 1.70GHz supports OpenCL 1.2
```

---

**The code of `helloworld.c`:**

```
//
// File:       hello.c
//
// Abstract:   A simple "Hello World" compute example showing basic usage of OpenCL which
//             calculates the mathematical square (X[i] = pow(X[i],2)) for a buffer of
//             floating point values.
//
//
// Version:    <1.0>
//
// Disclaimer: IMPORTANT:  This Apple software is supplied to you by Apple Inc. ("Apple")
//             in consideration of your agreement to the following terms, and your use,
//             installation, modification or redistribution of this Apple software
//             constitutes acceptance of these terms.  If you do not agree with these
//             terms, please do not use, install, modify or redistribute this Apple
//             software.
//
//             In consideration of your agreement to abide by the following terms, and
//             subject to these terms, Apple grants you a personal, non - exclusive
//             license, under Apple's copyrights in this original Apple software ( the
//             "Apple Software" ), to use, reproduce, modify and redistribute the Apple
//             Software, with or without modifications, in source and / or binary forms;
//             provided that if you redistribute the Apple Software in its entirety and
//             without modifications, you must retain this notice and the following text
//             and disclaimers in all such redistributions of the Apple Software. Neither
//             the name, trademarks, service marks or logos of Apple Inc. may be used to
//             endorse or promote products derived from the Apple Software without specific
//             prior written permission from Apple.  Except as expressly stated in this
//             notice, no other rights or licenses, express or implied, are granted by
//             Apple herein, including but not limited to any patent rights that may be
//             infringed by your derivative works or by other works in which the Apple
//             Software may be incorporated.
//
//             The Apple Software is provided by Apple on an "AS IS" basis.  APPLE MAKES NO
//             WARRANTIES, EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING WITHOUT LIMITATION THE IMPLIED
//             WARRANTIES OF NON - INFRINGEMENT, MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A
//             PARTICULAR PURPOSE, REGARDING THE APPLE SOFTWARE OR ITS USE AND OPERATION
//             ALONE OR IN COMBINATION WITH YOUR PRODUCTS.
//
//             IN NO EVENT SHALL APPLE BE LIABLE FOR ANY SPECIAL, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL OR
//             CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES ( INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF
//             SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS
//             INTERRUPTION ) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE, REPRODUCTION, MODIFICATION
//             AND / OR DISTRIBUTION OF THE APPLE SOFTWARE, HOWEVER CAUSED AND WHETHER
//             UNDER THEORY OF CONTRACT, TORT ( INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE ), STRICT LIABILITY OR
//             OTHERWISE, EVEN IF APPLE HAS BEEN ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
//
// Copyright ( C ) 2008 Apple Inc. All Rights Reserved.
//

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <OpenCL/opencl.h>

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Use a static data size for simplicity
//
#define DATA_SIZE (1024)

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Simple compute kernel which computes the square of an input array
//
const char *KernelSource = "\n" \
"__kernel void square(                                                       \n" \
"   __global float* input,                                              \n" \
"   __global float* output,                                             \n" \
"   const unsigned int count)                                           \n" \
"{                                                                      \n" \
"   int i = get_global_id(0);                                           \n" \
"   if(i < count)                                                       \n" \
"       output[i] = input[i] * input[i];                                \n" \
"}                                                                      \n" \
"\n";

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int err;                            // error code returned from api calls

    float data[DATA_SIZE];              // original data set given to device
    float results[DATA_SIZE];           // results returned from device
    unsigned int correct;               // number of correct results returned

    size_t global;                      // global domain size for our calculation
    size_t local;                       // local domain size for our calculation

    cl_device_id device_id;             // compute device id
    cl_context context;                 // compute context
    cl_command_queue commands;          // compute command queue
    cl_program program;                 // compute program
    cl_kernel kernel;                   // compute kernel

    cl_mem input;                       // device memory used for the input array
    cl_mem output;                      // device memory used for the output array

    // Fill our data set with random float values
    //
    int i = 0;
    unsigned int count = DATA_SIZE;
    for(i = 0; i < count; i++)
        data[i] = rand() / (float)RAND_MAX;

    // Connect to a compute device
    //
    int gpu = 1;
    err = clGetDeviceIDs(NULL, gpu ? CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU : CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU, 1, &device_id, NULL);
    if (err != CL_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Error: Failed to create a device group!\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // Create a compute context
    //
    context = clCreateContext(0, 1, &device_id, NULL, NULL, &err);
    if (!context)
    {
        printf("Error: Failed to create a compute context!\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // Create a command commands
    //
    commands = clCreateCommandQueue(context, device_id, 0, &err);
    if (!commands)
    {
        printf("Error: Failed to create a command commands!\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // Create the compute program from the source buffer
    //
    program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1, (const char **) & KernelSource, NULL, &err);
    if (!program)
    {
        printf("Error: Failed to create compute program!\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // Build the program executable
    //
    err = clBuildProgram(program, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if (err != CL_SUCCESS)
    {
        size_t len;
        char buffer[2048];

        printf("Error: Failed to build program executable!\n");
        clGetProgramBuildInfo(program, device_id, CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG, sizeof(buffer), buffer, &len);
        printf("%s\n", buffer);
        exit(1);
    }

    // Create the compute kernel in the program we wish to run
    //
    kernel = clCreateKernel(program, "square", &err);
    if (!kernel || err != CL_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Error: Failed to create compute kernel!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Create the input and output arrays in device memory for our calculation
    //
    input = clCreateBuffer(context,  CL_MEM_READ_ONLY,  sizeof(float) * count, NULL, NULL);
    output = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, sizeof(float) * count, NULL, NULL);
    if (!input || !output)
    {
        printf("Error: Failed to allocate device memory!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Write our data set into the input array in device memory
    //
    err = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(commands, input, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(float) * count, data, 0, NULL, NULL);
    if (err != CL_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Error: Failed to write to source array!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Set the arguments to our compute kernel
    //
    err = 0;
    err  = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), &input);
    err |= clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), &output);
    err |= clSetKernelArg(kernel, 2, sizeof(unsigned int), &count);
    if (err != CL_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Error: Failed to set kernel arguments! %d\n", err);
        exit(1);
    }

    // Get the maximum work group size for executing the kernel on the device
    //
    err = clGetKernelWorkGroupInfo(kernel, device_id, CL_KERNEL_WORK_GROUP_SIZE, sizeof(local), &local, NULL);
    if (err != CL_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Error: Failed to retrieve kernel work group info! %d\n", err);
        exit(1);
    }

    // Execute the kernel over the entire range of our 1d input data set
    // using the maximum number of work group items for this device
    //
    global = count;
    err = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(commands, kernel, 1, NULL, &global, &local, 0, NULL, NULL);
    if (err)
    {
        printf("Error: Failed to execute kernel!\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // Wait for the command commands to get serviced before reading back results
    //
    clFinish(commands);

    // Read back the results from the device to verify the output
    //
    err = clEnqueueReadBuffer( commands, output, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(float) * count, results, 0, NULL, NULL );
    if (err != CL_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Error: Failed to read output array! %d\n", err);
        exit(1);
    }

    // Validate our results
    //
    correct = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        if(results[i] == data[i] * data[i])
            correct++;
    }

    // Print a brief summary detailing the results
    //
    printf("Computed '%d/%d' correct values!\n", correct, count);

    // Shutdown and cleanup
    //
    clReleaseMemObject(input);
    clReleaseMemObject(output);
    clReleaseProgram(program);
    clReleaseKernel(kernel);
    clReleaseCommandQueue(commands);
    clReleaseContext(context);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Same question as [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18616599/how-to-run-apples-opencl-hello-world-example-in-xcode). Please read the spec and/or use the search.

You have a CPU device, and you don't find a GPU device with is rather logical.
A simple look to the previous sentence of the `if` has the answer.

Change `int gpu = 1;` by `int gpu = 0;`

However for a proper method use:

```
// Connect to a compute device
//
err = clGetDeviceIDs(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 1, &device_id, NULL);
if (err != CL_SUCCESS)
    err = clGetDeviceIDs(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, 1, &device_id, NULL);
if (err != CL_SUCCESS)
{
    printf("Error: Failed to create a device group!\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

**EDIT: Since it looks like the implementation returns an error, but the function worked fine after all.**

```
// Connect to a compute device
//
int num_devices = 0;
err = clGetDeviceIDs(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 1, &device_id, &num_devices );
if (num_devices == 0)
    err = clGetDeviceIDs(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, 1, &device_id, &num_devices );
if (num_devices == 0)
{
    printf("Error: Failed to create a device group!\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Comment: indeed works on Xcode, Yet doesn't work in bash `clang -framework OpenCL helloworld.c -o helloworld && ./helloworld;` +1

Comment: Does bash has proper paths set to the OpenCL directories?

Comment: I assume it does, since as I mentioned in my post above the code in [How can i test for OpenCL compability?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892955/how-can-i-test-for-opencl-compability) works fine.

Comment: @DaekZeros Which one?